LUKS Full disk encryption with smartcard and ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to move from ubuntu 22.04 to ubuntu 24.04.. I do this by fully install the new version and not upgrade.
I use full disk encryption in the installer and set a passphrase. Everything works fine and I can boot into ubuntu entering my passphrase at the boot screen.
After installation I want switch my LUKS device from a passphrase to smartcard with oepnsc to start my computer.
I used this script for many years for my ubuntu 22.04 installations
#!/bin/bash

KEY=/root/rootkey
PUB=/tmp/public_key.pem
ID=$(pkcs15-tool --list-keys 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'Auth ID' | grep ID | cut -d ':' -f2 | tail -n1)
pkcs15-tool --read-public-key $ID -o $PUB
sudo touch $KEY
sudo dd if=/dev/random of=$KEY bs=1 count=245 
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/nvme0n1p3 $KEY
sudo openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey $PUB -in /$KEY -out $KEY.enc
sudo chmod 400 $KEY.enc
sudo shred $PUB $KEY
sudo perl -pi.bkp -e "s|none|$KEY.enc|; s|luks|luks,keyscript=decrypt_opensc|" /etc/crypttab
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

Result is

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic cp:
Aufruf von stat für '/etc/reader.conf' nicht möglich: Datei oder
Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

My /etc/crypttab looks like this:
dm_crypt-0 UUID=4cf10ba8-f524-4736-87ab-04c667b6ded5 /root/rootkey.enc luks,keyscript=decrypt_opensc

After reboot I just see a loading wheel. Nothing changes after plugging in my smartcard.
What I am thinking about is:

The error message accoring to /etc/reader.conf was seen under ubuntu 22.04 too. So this shouldn't be the error.

In /etc/crypttab the device name is dm_crypt-0 but I add a key to /dev/nvme0n1p3 . I tried to change this but `sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0 reports "Device /dev/dm_crypt-0 is not a valid LUKS device."


Is there something I am missing? It seems that the initramfs is not updated properly
When I look at the script /usr/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_opensc I can see that things like opensc-tool and pkcs15-crypt must be included in the initramfs. They are available on my computer, but how does initramfs know that they need to be copied?
This is my LUKS setup after installing. I have two keys, passphrase and the new one for the smartcard. This shouldn't be a problem either.
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/nvme0n1p3 
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          4
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           4cf10ba8-f524-4736-87ab-04c667b6ded5
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
    length: (whole device)
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2id
    Time cost:  6
    Memory:     1048576
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       a0 af e3 2c 3c 72 10 18 eb b0 49 d0 01 82 51 78 
                67 3c 56 fb 5a 17 b7 26 2d 3d b6 cd 10 79 2f fb 
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha256
    Area offset:32768 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
  1: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2id
    Time cost:  8
    Memory:     1048576
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       02 a2 ff 3a 73 d5 8d 2d b9 5c 97 ef af 10 10 d8 
                77 b8 3c 8f 1b 0e 5f 28 13 ba 14 53 6d ef 5c 56 
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha256
    Area offset:290816 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
    Hash:       sha256
    Iterations: 257508
    Salt:       2d f7 42 0a f2 0d 89 c0 52 81 ce 2c d3 20 38 b8 
                2d 97 c7 62 2e 37 b5 54 91 39 f2 b9 58 38 c0 30 
    Digest:     71 56 1c 42 2b 54 c9 d4 ce 21 5f 94 62 6c f1 fa 
                a3 34 8a 32 4f 21 81 15 eb 6d 2b 77 0c 07 6f 24 

What is missing? Or at least how can I debug the situation?

I fully installed 24.04. I just wanted to mention that my scrip already worked in 22.04

I had exact the same problem, but not with Ubuntu but with Debian testing as well as unstable (and I use GnuPG with smartcard). Try to add --disable-polkit in the script /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptopensc as parameter when pcscd will be started and run update-initramfs -u (make a backup of your initrd before!). This was the solution for me.

Thanks a lot. I can't test it at the moment but I guess it will be the solution. I will mark the answer as correct as soon as I have tested it.

Partial answer so far
I found that pressing Esc you get the console messages, see picture:


winscard_svc.c:355 ContextThread Rejected unauthorized PC/SC client

This message makes me think that this has soemthing to do with this article about polkit rules for accessign a smartcard
In ubuntu 22.04 the libpscslite version is 1.9.5-3ubuntu1                              In contrast in ubuntu 24.04 the version is 2.0.3-1build1
The changelog of pcscd shows that polkit is enabled by default. And result of pcscd -v in a console confirms it on ubuntu 24.04.
My problem is pretty much summerized here (but without a solution)
But when I lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic | grep polkit I can see that polkit is included into initramfs.
Further informations for smartcards and polkit:
I still don't knwo how to allow access to the smartcard inside the initramfs. It seems the polkit daemon is running but the polkit rules are not copied to the initramfs.
